# Using a docker container within an Azure pipeline, the "geometry" type doesn't seem to be installed correctly

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, azure-devops, postgis

I cannot run the following script without receiving `"42704: type "postgis.geometry" does not exist"` specifically when it tries to create the `location` table:

```
create schema if not exists postgis;
set search_path to postgis;
create extension if not exists postgis schema postgis;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA postgis TO my_account; -- this line doesn't seem to make a difference

create table if not exists postgis.location
(
    id integer not null,
    geometry postgis.geometry
    );

alter table postgis.location owner to my_account;
```

Here is the docker compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis:14-3.3-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=my_account
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=**
      - POSTGRES_DB=**
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - local
```

In azure, we are using `ubuntu-latest`.

It works fine for everyone locally. The only difference is that we are all using windows machines.
What is missing in the azure/ubuntu environment that prevents this from running?

Comment: I'm confused here - it works with the docker-compose, but doesn't work when you use a completely different image in azure? Why aren't you using the same image in azure that's being used locally?

Comment: @AnyaShenanigans I think there was a misunderstanding. We are using the same docker compose file both locally and in the azure pipeline.. We just have windows machines and rely on wsl/docker whereas the azure pipeline is running ubuntu natively.

Comment: When you run the postgis container, the extension was already loaded into the public schema, and needs to be moved to the `postgis` schema for your code to work as-is. The answer I've left will _hopefully_ answer your question, but may lead you to use a different approach here.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how this should have ever worked on either windows or linux if you're using the postgis container - the error is relatively fundamental, and should have affected both.

First - the postgis container will start with the `postgis` extension loaded into the `public` schema. You can see this by looking at the extensions on a cleanly launched postgis container:

```
# psql -U my_account fred
psql (14.8)
Type "help" for help.

fred=# \dx
                                        List of installed extensions
          Name          | Version |   Schema   |                        Description
------------------------+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 fuzzystrmatch          | 1.1     | public     | determine similarities and distance between strings
 plpgsql                | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis                | 3.3.2   | public     | PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions
 postgis_tiger_geocoder | 3.3.2   | tiger      | PostGIS tiger geocoder and reverse geocoder
 postgis_topology       | 3.3.2   | topology   | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions
(5 rows)
```

Any attempt to reinstantiate the extension into the postgis schema fails with the following warning:

```
fred=# create extension if not exists postgis schema postgis;
NOTICE:  extension "postgis" already exists, skipping
CREATE EXTENSION
```

This means the extension `postgis` is still in the public schema - which is why your create table is failing.

You should, in theory, be able to move the extension to a different schema with a single command, however when we attempt to do this we encounter:

```
fred=# ALTER EXTENSION postgis SET SCHEMA postgis;
ERROR:  extension "postgis" does not support SET SCHEMA
```

as we can see, this fails. You can alter the schema to make it relocatable, and the change the schema:

```
fred=# UPDATE pg_extension SET extrelocatable = TRUE WHERE extname = 'postgis';
UPDATE 1
fred=# ALTER EXTENSION postgis SET SCHEMA postgis;
ALTER EXTENSION
```

And then your subsequent create table will work, with the `postgis.geometry` field type.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why I'm not able to see that "skipping" message. I'll try this out tonight. Thank you!